# Where are save files located for Watch Dogs in my Windows PC?

Tags: watch-dogs

I was looking to transfer my saved progress of Watch Dogs to a new Windows PC from my old PC. Where are the Save files located?

I have tried these locations:
Program Files/Ubisoft
Program Files (x86)/Ubisoft
Program Data/Steam

but the files were not present.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was present in

> C:\ProgramData\Orbit\274\GMT-MAX.ORG

or

> C:\ProgramData\Orbit\

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the game and install it via UPlay then save games will be in the default UPlay location of "Where you installed UPlay"\savegames, for example C:\Program Files\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\savegames